# Pandas custom second level groupby function

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sku_id' : ['A','A','A','B','C','C'],
                  'order_counts' : [1,2,3,1,1,2],
                  'order_val' : [10,20,30,10,10,20]})
```

which creates:

[image: output from first example]

A simple `groupby()` of `sku_id` using `df.groupby('sku_id').sum()` would give:

[image: output from second example]

And a two-level grouping `df.groupby(['sku_id', 'order_counts']).sum()` would give:

[image: output from third example]

But now I want a custom second-level grouping on `order_counts` such that any `order_counts == 1` is considered a group and any `order_counts > 1` are grouped together in a group labelled `R` (for Repeat order)

The result would look like this:

```
sku_id order_counts  order_val         
A      1                    10
       R                    50                           
B      1                    10
C      1                    10
       R                    20
```

Is there a way to supply a custom groupby function to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Mask` the `!= 1` values in the `order_counts` column with `R`, then use `groupby` + `sum`

```
g = df['order_counts'].mask(df['order_counts'] != 1, 'R')
df.groupby(['sku_id', g])['order_val'].sum()
```

Result

```
sku_id  order_counts
A       1               10
        R               50
B       1               10
C       1               10
        R               20
Name: order_val, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

How about just `assign` before you `groupby`?

```
new_df = (df
    .assign(order_counts=lambda x: np.where(x['order_counts'] > 1, 'R', x['order_counts']))
    .groupby(['sku_id', 'order_counts'])
    .sum()
)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
                     order_val
sku_id order_counts           
A      1                    10
       R                    50
B      1                    10
C      1                    10
       R                    20
```